# Facebook Graph Api for iOS giving error validating application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been running through [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app) and everything has been going fine until I try to post to a users wall. I can get the user's info, first name, last name, education and such. But when I do the following:

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"]];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Posted from Swangle for iPhone" forKey:@"message"];
[request setPostValue:@"Swangle for Iphone" forKey:@"name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Coming Soon..." forKey:@"caption"];
[request setPostValue:@"Description" forKey:@"description"];
[request setPostValue:_accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postToWallFinished:)];

[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];


- (void)postToWallFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    NSLog(@"Response String : %@ and request : %@", responseString, request);

    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *postId = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"Post id is: %@", postId);

    UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sucessfully posted to photos & wall!" 
                                                  message:@"Check out your Facebook to see!"
                                                 delegate:nil 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [av show];

}
```

I am returned

```
Post id is : {"error":{"message":"Error validating application.","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

I know that the access_token is correct because I am allowed to login with it.

Also I created an application on developers.facebook, and am using the correct key to access their DB.

Can someone please advise me, or point me in the right direction to figure this out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked for the authorization to post to the user wall?

From Facebook Graph API page:

**Authorization**

**The Graph API as such allows you to easily access all public information about an object. For example, https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor (Bret Taylor) returns all the public information about Bret. For example a user's first name, last name and profile picture are publicly available.**

**To get additional information about a user, you must first get their permission. At a high level, you need to get an access token for the Facebook user. After you obtain the access token for the user, you can perform authorized requests on behalf of that user by including the access token in your Graph API requests**

Take a look here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: ya when i logged in the first time i was asked for authorization which i said yes to.